# Ubuntu command display man -k

Tags: documentation

What does the man -k command display?

- All man pages in sequence with the given name in all chapters.
- The man pages with a word in the name.
- The manual page for the given topic.
- A list of the man pages discussing the subject.

Comment: You can use `man -k '\bman\b'` to find the man page of `man`! Now you know where to look: `man man`!

Comment: @VolkerSiegel may I ask for you?  How we will find more accurately all .cpp files in the users home directory that were modified no more than 5 minutes ago?

Comment: You should look for similar questions with answers, and if you do not find one that helps, ask it as a separate question. Answering here does not help anybode else but you, because it can not be found.

Comment: This question was lifted verbatim from the [Linux Foundation 101x course](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-linux-linuxfoundationx-lfs101x-2). The question is poorly-worded for the context of the course as it is similar to, but different from, information given previously in the course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [`man man`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/man.1.php) lol!

```
man -k printf
     Search the short descriptions and manual page names for the keyword printf as regular
     expression.  Print out any matches.  Equivalent to apropos -r printf.
```

```
-K
   Search for the specified string in all man pages. Warning: this is probably very 
slow! It helps to specify a section. (Just to give a rough idea, on my machine this takes 
about a minute per 500 man pages.)
```

Comment: +1 on `man man` - there's even more meta-man! (see comment on question)

Comment: may ask What is displayed when running man with no options other than the topic as an argument?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel This is a nice `man man`. thanks

Comment: @qwerty `"What manual page do you want?"`

Comment: no i have ask when running man with no options other than the topic as an argument

Comment: @qwerty I said. if you run `man` in Terminal you will see this output `"What manual page do you want?"`

Comment: @qwerty your question already answered and if you delete your question more times you will ban for asking !! thanks

Comment: @KasiyA i can't delete) may I ask for you? How we will find more accurately all .cpp files in the users home directory that were modified no more than 5 minutes ago?

Comment: @qwerty sure. But you have to ask it as new question ;) thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/man.1.html

"When you search for manpages with man's -k switch, the entire NAME line of every manpage is searched and the results (if any) are displayed."

See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/man.1.html for details.

Comment: this means the manual page for the given topic or a list of the man pages discussing the subject???